# QRegularExpression and the rule of using backslash

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

In [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html), it states

> Note that due to C++ literal strings rules, you must escape all
>   backslashes inside the pattern string with another backslash:

But I deliberately ignored the backslash and the code is running without even a warning. The only thing I get is the Editor of Qt Creator mentions 
`unknown escape sequence '\d'`.

My question is what are the consequences of ignoring backslashes in the regular expressions (*i.e.* I will not do it though in my applications).

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QRegularExpression>
#include <QDebug>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QRegularExpression regex("\d"); \\ the correct way is "\\d"

    // Validate the regular exression. 
    if(regex.isValid()){
        qDebug() << "The regular expression is VALID.";
        QRegularExpressionMatch match = regex.match("abc123 def");
        bool hasMatch = match.hasMatch(); 
        qDebug() << hasMatch;
    }else {
        qDebug() << "The regular expression INVALID.";
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

The output is

```
The regular expression is VALID.
true
```

Comment: To get a single backslash in a character literal `"\d"`you'll need to escape it with another one `"\\d"`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I'm aware of this but my question is the code is running and it validates it successfully. I can't see the consequences of ignoring the backslash. The compiler is not complaining not even a warning.

Comment: Any suitably configured build system (e.g. compile with `-Wall -Werror`) should catch undefined escape sequences and fail accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All major compilers (gcc, clang, msvc, icc) complain about `\d` being an unrecognized escape sequence by default (i.e. the warning is enabled by default in all of them, at least in their latest versions).

What they all do is treat `\d` as if you had simply typed `d`.

Therefore, in your case, the final string would be `"d"`, which in turn is a valid regular expression, and indeed it matches `"abc123 def"` because there is a `d` there.

Note that this has nothing to do with Qt: it does not parse C++ nor can complain about escape sequences; that is the job of the compiler. What Qt sees is whatever string the compiler ended up constructing from the source code.

To avoid further issues like this, please do not ignore warnings (and re-enable them if you disabled them).